# Deploying sensitive data using ansible-vault

Tags: ansible

I want to deploy a docker-compose application which has sensitive data using Ansible and Ansible-Vault.
Ansible clones the repository to a server, moves it to an appropiate location and starts the Docker container.
The application has sensitive files with environment variables in a subpath of the docker-compose.yaml file.

How can I obscure the sensitive parts of the files while leaving the rest intact? I understand, that variables can be encrypted using ansible-vault and be called inside Ansible but I need them in plaintext on the server. Or is there another way?

Basically I want to leave as much information as possible in the repository of the docker-compose application and only deploy the sensitive data with Ansible. I thought of simply placing all environment files in Ansible and encrypt the sensitive parts but this solution splits information in two repositories which I don't like.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose file supports [reading environment variables from a file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file), thus, I would guess you would want to just copy the docker compose file as is, which contains only cleartext, and then write out the environment file containing the secrets that are encrypted using ansible-vault

given a docker compose of approximately:

```yaml
services:
  hello:
    image: busybox
    env_file:
    - /run/hello.env
```

then the playbook would look something like:

```yaml
tasks:
- copy:
    dest: /run/hello.env
    content: |
       SUPER_SEKRIT={{ the_vaulted_value }}
    mode: '0600'
```

*I haven't actually tried this specific solution, so that's why I said "something like" ...*